# How does a program read unicode?

Tags: java, unicode

Unicode code units can be of variable size since characters can be represented by 2 bytes or more bytes (sequence of 2 bytes). So if stored in binary format, how can a program know how to read them back?

Lets say 'a' is represented by `0F0F 13F3` and 'b' is represented by `02AD BC39 09F3 459F`

If I write them in file foo.txt:

```
0F0F 13F3 02AD BC39 09F3 459F
```

Then how would I know where to stop for 'a' and 'b'?

Guys here I am talking about reading , writing pure unicode i.e without converting it into any other format based upon popular charset such as utf-8 .

Comment: Terminology is important when discussing Unicode: you are blurring code units, code points, and characters together (they are three different terms). Once one decides on an encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32) code units are fixed length. (1, 2, and 4 bytes, resp.) Code points, however, can require multiple code units in UTF-8 and UTF-16. In addition to the good answers below, see unicode.org/glossary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, not all Unicode representations are variable length. UTF-32 and USC-2 are fixed length. UTF-8 and UTF-16 are each in their own way variable length.

Second, if you read the specification, you will learn that the sequences are self-describing. The byte values (in UTF-8) that can be first bytes can't be second or third, etc. Ditto for the surrogate pairs that represent non-BMP characters in UTF-16.

Answer (score 2):

A commonly used encoding is [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). The way it's structured is that some predefined bits of the character's bytes tell you whether there are more bytes to come.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Design for a nice diagram.

Comment: I am interested in reading Unicode as it is without without encoding it into any charset .

Comment: Unicode is a set of character definations, not an encoding. UTF-7, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, those are encodings of Unicode. What you deal with in binary data is encodings. You need to determine what encoding is used before you can read it.  Sometimes data has a BOM in front to tell you the encoding.  If not, then you have to rely on external information to know what the encoding is.